# weird admob problem

Tags: android, admob

I did some updates to my application today but now admob dont work right and it gives me an error in the ad saying `adview missing xml attribute "adsize"`. now the changes i made have nothing to do with the ads and they have been the same since I implemented them and worked

this is my xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.notify.me.lite"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout1"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"> 
            <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                     ads:adUnitId="id"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>   
    <WebView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/webView1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and where its implemented

```
public class Main extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_webview);

    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about.html");
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(request);
}
```

as you can see adsize is there in the xml file so there should be no reason why I should be getting that error. Ideas as to why this is happening all of the sudden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why its suddenly stoped working but whenever i use Admob i always put it in a seperate layout, with xml like:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rLayAdMob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dip">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in the onCreate function i setup the adView like:

```
adView = new AdView(Menu.this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rLayAdMob);
layout.addView(adView);
```

I've never had any issues doing it this way, and would only require a small change to your code.

Hope this helps,

Kenny

Comment: i switched to your method and it woks again though i am still puzzled as to why mine dont work anymore

Answer (score 1):

Google updated the AdMob library but did not yet document the required changes, as per this forum [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/3b885d3fe5bb21a5)

The substance of the change is to update the ads namespace:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```